# How to develop a wifi sync app for PC to Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, synchronized, wifi-direct

I want to develop a wifi sync app for pc to windows phone.Any idea about how to start?

Comment: have you tried googling first?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [MS Synch Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)

Comment: Yes as long as the devices are connected in the same network.